# How to hide the keyboard programmatically in iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, iphone-softkeyboard

How to hide the keyboard programmatically in iphone?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Tell the UIResponder subclass that is currently first responder to resign its first responder status:

```
[responder resignFirstResponder];
```

Answer (score 20):

```
[textFieldName resignFirstResponder];
```

Answer (score 4):

It's easy:

#### ObjC

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] endEditing:YES];
```

#### Swift

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.endEditing(true)
```

take a look at [UIView Class Reference for endEditing](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1619630-endediting).
Causes the view (or one of its embedded text fields) to resign the first responder status. And [keyWindow](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwindow/1621612-keywindow) is the only window that receives keyboard events, so this solution is guarantied to always work.

Answer (score 2):

Call this in your ViewController

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **textview** then

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView
 shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range
replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
  if ([text isEqualToString:@"\n"])
 {
    [textView resignFirstResponder];
    [self keyboardWillHide];
 }
}
```

and if you are using **textfield** then

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*)textField;
 {

[textField resignFirstResponder];

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the swift version:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().sendAction("resignFirstResponder", to:nil, from:nil, forEvent:nil)
```