# Hide Input Keyboard on iPhone Without Knowing First Responder?

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586937/how-to-hide-the-keyboard-programatically-in-iphone), but the question is how to know which textView is the first responder? [This question looked promising](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949806/is-there-a-way-to-detect-what-uiview-is-currently-visible) to figure out the first responder, but it turns out that it calls private APIs. Is there any way to hide the keyboard or to figure out the first responder as the-one-who-has-the-keyboard?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Easy way to dismiss keyboard?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/741185/easy-way-to-dismiss-keyboard)

Comment: Also see [Dismiss keyboard on touch anywhere outside of textfield](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11274119/dismiss-keyboard-on-touch-anywhere-outside-uitextfield)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's easy:

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] endEditing:YES];
```

take a look at [UIView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/endEditing:).

Comment: I'll have to verify this before marking it as accepted. On the other hand, if you linked to some docs, that would be better for me and SO.

Comment: UIWindow is a subclass of UIView; it inherits `endEditing` method from UIView.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me - my use case was i have 4 different tableViews on a  UIView that have their hidden property turned on and off by a UISegmentedController making just one appear at a time. - i needed to get the keyboard to go away if someone changed to a different table view.

Answer (score 4):

`[textView isFirstResponder]` should tell you if it's the first responder. I guess you could just loop through all text fields in your class to check if it's the first responder.

Or you could just call resignFirstResponder on every textField, and it'll still work.

Comment: Actually on second thought, the second part of your answer makes me realize that thanks to my well-designed app :), I can just do that.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you should pick something to become the first responder, something which probably doesn't do anything on its own, and call `-[UIResponder becomeFirstResponder]` on it.  This would work well with a UIViewController or UIWindow (which you can get through `-[UIView window]`, I think) because these would have the most similar responder chains, and would make the current firstResponder loose its firstResponder status, dismissing the keyboard, but also wouldn't bring up the keyboard, as it would not be a UITextField.