# how to show the UItableViewcell where the user is writing?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a tableView with a lot of field, like a form. The question is that when the user is changing to the next row, if the row is bellow the keyboard, the user does not see the label nor the text his writing.

I have try to use:

```
NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row + 1 inSection:indexPath.section];

[self.theTable scrollToRowAtIndexPath:path atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

but without success.

Let me tell you that the viewController is controlling a view, with a table inside it. The table is not the view itself.

How can I make the cell becomes visible, so that the user can see, even if that's the last row of the table (has about 20 rows)?

Comment: Why scrollToRowIndex does not work?

Comment: @sergio i don't know. perhaps because the view has a uiimage on the background, and a uitableview, i mean, th tableview is not the view itself...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use a subclass of `UITableViewController` (which already handles this automatically) or resize your table view when the keyboard becomes visible, so that it's not behind the keyboard. You can also use the `contentInset` property instead of changing the table view's `frame`.

To be notified when the keyboard shows or hides, listen for `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` and `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification`.

Answer (score 0):

For handling the keyboard yourself look at this answer [resize UIView when showing the keyboard for iphone, how to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5408848/resize-uiview-when-showing-the-keyboard-for-iphone-how-to/5409152#5409152)